# Accesst to $scope variable that its name is stored in another variable

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

see code...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="My.VarInScope1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="My.VarInScope2" />
```

and angularjs

```
var varname = 'My.VarInScope1';

$scope.varname = 'Hi'; ????
$scope[varname] = 'Hi'; ????
```

How can I do it?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

```
$parse(varname).assign($scope, value)
```

( In this concrete example you can do `$scope.My.VarInScope1 = 'Hi'` ofc)